# Where to mount EFS on ECS wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

```
root@e532hrwha:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

I am running wordpress,

This is my docker container file structure, I want to mount EFS on it for persistent file storage so that even when my ec2 instance crashes or terminates i am able to retain my data

Where should i mount my EFS file system ?

**I have tried**

1) Mounting it on `/mnt` which gives me error saying `you dont have permission to access this resource`(I have given all possible access

2) mounting it on var/www/html

However neither of them seem to work as my wordpress uses old data even though the file system is correctly mounted when i try to ssh into it and see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using the official WordPress docker image, what you need to persists is your `wp-content` folder... so you should mount your EFS volume at `/var/www/html/wp-content`

Comment: `var/www/html` I mounted it here is it too much different from `/var/www/html/wp-content` ?? if i mount all the other things aswell will that break my site ?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60090126/how-to-persist-my-database-in-wordpress-when-running-docker-image-of-wordpress-o

Comment: I had tried and this doesn't work fully. If you mount until `/var/www/html/wp-content` then you are persisting the `plugins` and `themes` folder too. Next time, when you apply `wordpress` image with updated plugins or themes, it wont happen as EFS will override wit it's contents.