# How to persist my database in Wordpress when running docker image of Wordpress on ECS?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I am running a docker image of wordpress on ECS

I am using database as Aurora `"name": "WORDPRESS_DB_HOST",`

and                           `"value": "db.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"`

**PROBLEM**

If i terminate my ECS instance and run the same task on another ECS instance then the database is not persisting

**What i want**

The database to persist so that when i run wordpress on another ECS instance i can run the same instance of the wordpress that is i dont have to reinstall or repost or reconfigure any of my posts/settings

**What i have done so far**

I mounted EFS on `var/www/html/wp-content` ,What this basically does is persist my wp data only

**Question**

Is there any way i can make the installation,configuration,log in data etc to persist ? So i can run the task configuration in lets say any ECS instance and then be able to access my wordpress site without setup and reposting all my content ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an RDS instance, just be sure to add the proper database-related environment variables to the WordPress docker image:

```sh
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=...
WORDPRESS_DB_USER=...
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=...
WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=...
```

You can read the full [README](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) file for the official WordPress Docker image to understand all the options.

Comment: I think what is happening is my wordpress is getting installed locally on the ec2 instance EBS volume ,That is why when i terminate and launch a new instance wordpress is no longer installed.... I have to make it such that the EBS volume is backed up and mounts on the new ec2 instance for it to work... hope it makes sense :) i don't think its an RDS issue but an ec2 issue